# How to wrap content with a tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink

When I click one of the `li` item I want to open a div that contains a form:

```js
$(settings.dom.wrapperID).wrap('<a href="#login-box"/>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="js-news">

  <li class="news-item">This is text 1 ...</li>
  <li class="news-item">This is text 2 ...</li>
  <li class="news-item">This is text 3 ...</li>
  <li class="news-item">This is text 4 ...</li>

</ul>
```

If I make an normal a tag and put `#login-box` in the link works fine, but not with jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, by adding `http://` right before your link, like this:

```
$(settings.dom.wrapperID).wrap('<a href="http://www.google.com"/>');
```

Comment: of course. 
what if i want to link to at html form? it's in a div and the div is hidden.
`'<a href="#form"/>'`

But nothing happens

It works if i just make a normal link without jquery.

Comment: What's the expected result by using `'<a href="#form"/>'`? Scrolling to the form?

Comment: The reson why i have to wrap the li's is becuse the client kan modify the li. Add, remove, edit but the link has to stay the same and link to a form.

I got a normal button that links to the form and it's work. But it dose not when i try through jQ

Comment: Sorry I do not understand your issue. Maybe by adding a slightly more HTML/JS code, it will help us?